# About exponential martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider the stochastic process defined by

$$ Z_t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}} \exp \left( \frac{-B^2_t}{2\left( 1-t\right)} \right ) , t \geq 0$$
where $ \left(B_t\right)_{t\geq 0}$ is a real standard brownian motion starting from zero.

I'd like to show that $\left(Z_t\right)_{t\geq 0} $ is a exponential martingale for $t \in \left [ 0, 1\right [$.

For it, I'd like to use the following theorem:

> **Theorem:** If $ M = \left(M_t\right)_{t\geq 0}$ is an adapted, continuous process, null at zero and $ V = \left(V_t\right)_{t\geq 0}$
>   is a increasing, continuous and adapted process, null at zero, then
>   are equivalent:
>
> (i) $ M = \left(M_t\right)_{t\geq 0}$is a local continuous martingale
>   and $ \langle M \rangle_t= V_t,\  \forall{t\geq 0}$
>
> (ii) For all $\lambda \in R$, $ X^\lambda_t = \exp \left(\lambda M_t
>  -\frac{\lambda}{2}V_t \right)$ is a positive local continuous martingale.

Note that $$ Z_t =  \exp \left( \frac{-B^2_t}{2\left( 1-t\right)} - \frac{1}{2} \log \left( 1-t\right) \right ) $$

and by Itô's lemma

$$ M_t :=\frac{-B^2_t}{2\left( 1-t\right)} = - \int_0 ^t \frac{B_s}{\left( 1-s\right)}dB_s -\int_0 ^t \frac{-B^2_s}{2\left( 1-s\right)} ds - \int_0 ^t \frac{1}{\left( 1-s\right)}ds .$$

Also, we have

$$ \langle M \rangle_t = \int_0 ^t \frac{B^2_s}{\left( 1-s\right)^2}d\langle B \rangle_s =\int_0 ^t \frac{B^2_s}{\left( 1-s\right)^2}ds$$

and $$ \mathbb E \langle M \rangle_t =  \int_0 ^t \frac{ \mathbb E \left[ B^2_s\right ] }{\left( 1-s\right)^2}ds =  \int_0 ^t \frac{ s }{\left( 1-s\right)^2}ds = - \log(1-t) < \infty , \  \forall t \in \left[0,1 \right[ $$

Nevertheless, I'm still not capable to see how  to manipulate $Z_t$ in order to apply the theorem. Perhaps, there is an alternative to usage of this theorem.

Someone could help me please?

Comment: Be careful, $\dfrac{B_t^2}{(1-t)}$ is not a local martingale.

Comment: @Ju'x: I've not said it was I've just cald it $M_t$. Anyway, thank you very much for your answer that undid my confusion.

Comment: I know, it was just a small warning. Anyway, glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Kiyoshi Itō's lemma:
$$
\frac{B_t^2}{2(1-t)} = \int_0^t\frac{B_s}{1-s}dB_s + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\frac{ds}{1-s}+ \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \frac{B_s^2}{(1-s)^2}ds.
$$

The term $M_t = \displaystyle\int_0^t \frac{B_s}{1-s}dB_s$ is a continuous local martingale with quadratic variation given by:
$$
\langle M \rangle_t = \int_0^t\frac{B_s^2}{(1-s)^2}ds.
$$

In other words,
$$
\exp\left\{-\frac{B_t^2}{2(1-t)} - \frac{1}{2}\ln(1-t)\right\} = \exp\left\{-M_t - \frac{1}{2}\langle M\rangle_t\right\}
$$
is an exponential local martingale.